# openpyxl не корректно удаляет строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Когда я удаляю строки через openpyxl то они удаляются не корректно. В каких то местах даже остаются. Нужна удалить строки полностью, как это делает excel. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
import openpyxl

this_book = openpyxl.open( "example.xlsx" )
this_book.active = 1

def result_i():
    ''' Функция заполняет таблицу и возвращает строку на которой закончилось заполнение '''
    return 10

i = result_i()

if i < 255:
    #В нашем шаблоне 255 строк и на 255 расположена формула которая считает таблицу.
    #В теории из-за удаления строк она должна перемещатся на верх.
    this_book.active.delete_rows(i, 255-i)

this_book.save("result.xlsx")
this_book.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KINvDVnSBvAFu7A-Yv3hV-gfWDspLDcg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как Microsoft Office удаляет слияние ячеек, я ожидал такого же поведения и у openpyxl. Но как оказалось строки удаляются, а слияние ячеек остается. Решение проблемы.`this_book.active.merge_cells( 'A2:A' + str(i) )`
А вот так вот я исправлял формулы. `this_book.active['H' + str(i)].value = '=SUM(H4:H'+str(i-1)+')'`